# Is there a way I can view the sum of my theoretical meta rep?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, meta

I know I can do a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/englishmeta/s/824/how-much-rep-would-i-have-if-there-were-no-rep-cap-fixed?UserId=10041), but that only updates every month or so, and right now it's stuck at 70, which doesn't help.  I could also do the math, looking at [this page](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10041/drm65?tab=reputation) (133 total), but that could eventually get old.  I tried simply https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/reputation, but that says:

> Reputation on this per-site meta is derived entirely from the main site; nothing to show.

Which... well, doesn't help, either.

I know it's not terribly important that I know my meta score, but since there is a separate reputation page for meta, I wondered if there is something that adds up the day-by-day scores, or if one is forced to do the math.

Comment: why would you want this?

Comment: Seeing the meta reputation of other users could give a indication of the participation of users to meta, but as users are used that down-voting on a meta site doesn't have visible consequences on the reputation (as a meta site shows the main-site reputation) you could find users with a meta reputation close to the minimal, but not because they didn't participate (it could be quite the opposite). I don't see any reason for seeing my own meta reputation, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no convenient way to get the full detail of your Meta reputation. All routes which formerly worked to this effect (reputation audit, the old graph, and the even older tri-monthly sums) have since been removed. The swiftest option, however unwieldy it actually is, is to manually do the math.